# How can I open a terminal window on OSX?

Tags: macos

I am doing some testing on a computer running Mac OSX Yosemite.
How can I open a terminal? - note the command key doesn't work either.
Ive googled, but no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you open a finder window and go to the `Applications` folder and into the `Utilities` subfolder, you should find terminal there. Double click and Terminal should start.

Another option is to use spotlight search by either clicking the search (magnifying glass) icon in the top right corner of the mac's top bar or use the default <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to bring it (spotlight search). Then start typing "Terminal" and you should get it as a suggestion.

Comment: Alright - got there! Thanks for your your prompt response - really saved me alot of unecessary frustration!

Answer (score 0):

There is a System shortcut available [but I don't think activated by default] in System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services to open a New Terminal [or tab] at the current folder.

[image]

You can set this to work just in the right click menu, under Services, or add a hot key.

[image]